# XNA HLSL Exclude texture?

Tags: xna, hlsl

I'm going through HLSL tutorials and I have lighting and texturing setup. Right now in my shader I take a texture, but if I leave that variable blank it gives me an error. Half of my models have textures and the other half don't, is there a way to "skip" the texturing part for the models that don't have them and set it for the models that do without having to make a completely seperate shader that only deals with lighting?

Also, whilst I'm asking this, is saturate and normalize the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: No, [saturate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509645.aspx) and [normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509630.aspx) are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use two separate shaders to achieve this.  Probably the best way to go about this is to add preprocessor directives to remove your texture code when a certain symbol is defined i.e.:

```
#if USE_TEXTURES
//texturing sctuff here
#endif
```

This makes it easier to maintain changes that would affect both shaders.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "skip" texturing, but if you don't want to make two separate shaders, you could simply create a 1x1 white texture and use that for all the untextured models.